# Highcharts - Put different URL to each of data in donut-pie

Tags: highcharts

I use donut-pie chart from highcharts and I would like to add a different url to each of my data.For example

```
data = [{
  y: 35,
  color: colors[0],
  url: 'http://www.google.com',
  drilldown: {
    name: 'Animals',
    categories: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'],
    data: [20, 10, 5],
    url: ['http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.facebook.com','http://www.hotmail.com'],
    color: colors[0]
  }
}
```

The url 'http://www.google.com' is work but url in drilldown not working.I put this in series

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function () {
            location.href = this.options.url;
        }
    }
}
```

and put this in data arrays

```
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add service data
    servicesData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color,
        url: data[i].url
    });

    // add status data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
        brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
        statusData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get(),
            url: data[i].drilldown.data[j].url
        });
    }
}
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner loop (`// add status data`) you are setting:

```
url: data[i].drilldown.data[j].url
```

If you look at your `data` structure you'll see that `data[i].drilldown.data[j]` has no `url` attribute. `data[j]` is just a plain number, while `data[i]` is an object.

The quick fix is changing it to:

```
url: data[i].drilldown.url[j]
```

Alternatively you could restructure your data so that the inner data has the same format as the outer data, making them both objects.